# focus() or select() method javascript, slow performance in Chrome

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, select, focus

Well i notice a performance problem in chrome, if i do:

```
console.time('someFunction timer');

//one of both

//document.getElementById("R_"+row+"_C_"+(col+1)+"_D_"+day).focus();
document.getElementById("R_"+row+"_C_"+(col+1)+"_D_"+day).select();
console.timeEnd('someFunction timer');
```

Time is about: 150ms in chrome and only 15ms in firefox. Is any problem with focus() method or select() method in chrome?

If i use jQuery times are similar like:

```
console.time('someFunction timer');

//one of both

//$("#R_"+row+"_C_"+(col+1)+"_D_"+day).focus();
$("#R_"+row+"_C_"+(col+1)+"_D_"+day).select();
console.timeEnd('someFunction timer');
```

**SOLVED Temporary:**

Well i found a temporary solution, problem is in Chrome, when work with many (thousands) of input text, goes slowly. Solution for me is remove form tags, and then when i click in submit button, catch it with jQuery and create a new form, and append to body and then submit this new form with only changed inputs.

```
             for (var z=1;z<=48;z++){
                 var select = $("#R_"+i+"_C_"+z+"_D_"+day);
                 bodyform += '<input type="text" name="ID_'+select.data("idp")+'_C_'+select.data("coll")+'_D_'+day+'_H_'+z+'" value="'+select.val()+'"/>';
            }

            $("#plantables").append('<form id="myForm" style="margin: 0px;" action="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route') , {'shop':app.request.get('shop'),'iduniverse': universe.iduniverso}) }}" method="post">'+bodyform+'</form>');
            //$("#plantables").after('</form>');
            $("#myForm").submit();
```

Another trick is to delete name property of input, i see that decrease speed if exists, but then problem is when you need to send form, this inputs doens´t attach to post, but if named just before send you solve it.

Same thing with id property.

Firefox or IExplorer works fine with forms and inputs.

Comment: Maybe, but i think too its a problem of number of inputs, i´ve got about 3000inputs in the same page

Comment: if i delete name attr of input it increase performance, about 100ms, if i delete id it´s better but then i need to acces by id to do more changes...

Answer (score 0):

focus() is a dom API. it is responsible for reflow the element.It recalculates the position of the element and blocks the browser for performing any other action.
there are few methods which are responsible for reflow. you can check here:
https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a